# sqlite not working on iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have a weird problem. My app works fine on my device but the sqlite database does not work on the simulator. The file "database.sqlite" exists in the same folder as my apps, it has the same name and the columns names are also correct.

So I assume there is something wrong with the configuration but I don't know what. Can someone please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some posts that seem to address the problem : http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=484899

Answer (score 0):

One reason might be because you should ensure the database is copied from your Supporting Files application directory (read only) to library or documents before you use it.  Here's an ensurePrepared function from a sample of mine that uses sqlite that does just that.  In this case, it's called contacts.db

```
- (BOOL)ensureDatabasePrepared: (NSError **)error
{
    // already prepared
    if ((_dbPath != nil) &&
        ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:_dbPath]))
    {
        return YES;
    }

    // db in main bundle - cant edit.  copy to library if !exist
    NSString *dbTemplatePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contacts" ofType:@"db"];
    NSLog(@"%@", dbTemplatePath);

    NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    _dbPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"];

    NSLog(@"dbPath: %@", _dbPath);

    // copy db from template to library
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:_dbPath])
    {
        NSLog(@"db not exists");
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:dbTemplatePath toPath:_dbPath error:&error])
        {
            return NO;
        }

        NSLog(@"copied");
    }    

    return YES;    
}
```